# What is the difference between setsockopt and ioctl with SIOCSIFFLAGS?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

To set a network interface to promiscuous mode, for example, one can use `setsockopt` as

```c
struct packet_mreq opt;
opt.mr_ifindex = the_very_interface_index;
setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void*)&opt, sizeof(opt));
```

On the other hand, [as packet(7) suggested](https://linux.die.net/man/7/packet), one can also use `ioctl` with SIOCSIFFLAGS option, like

```c
struct ifreq req;
strcpy(req.ifr_name, the_very_interface_name);
ioctl(socket_fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &req);
req.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
ioctl(socket_fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &req);
```

I understand these two ways are completely equivalent, but is there any difference? Otherwise, why is there two ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very little difference between the two, as can be seen by perusing the source. Specifically, consider callers of [`__dev_set_promiscuity`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/__dev_set_promiscuity).

- The [`setsockopt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/PACKET_MR_PROMISC) interface eventually calls [`dev_set_promiscuity`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/dev_set_promiscuity).
- The [`ioctl`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/dev_ifsioc) interface ends up calling [`dev_change_flags`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/dev_change_flags).

There has always been some duplication of mechanisms due to the file descriptor interface to devices. For example `send()` vs `write()`. To be honest, I have never thought too deeply about it. I imagine `ioctl` interfaces are a natural thing to add for generic devices, and `setsockopt` interfaces are natural to add for sockets, so both end up existing. You could think of sockets as a higher level abstraction over the network device, so a higher level interface to modify options would not be an unreasonable addition.